# Simple Inverse Logic

Tags: logic, inverse, quantifiers

I have the following statement: "Every number besides 0 has a unique multiplicative inverse."

I am curious as to why the following does not work:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R_{ \neq 0}} \exists y,z \in \mathbb{R_{\neq 0}} : ((xy = 1) \cap (xz =1)) \iff (y =z)$$

From my understanding, the following is correct, but am told that there needs to be universal quantifier for z instead. Why is this the case?

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R_{ \neq 0}} \exists y,z \in \mathbb{R_{\neq 0}} :
(xy =1 ) \land (xz = 1) \implies (y = z) $$

I'm assuming the following doesn't hold because (y = z) can be false, while the other predicate is true:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R_{ \neq 0}} \exists y,z \in \mathbb{R_{\neq 0}} :
(y = z) \implies (xy =1 ) \land (xz = 1) $$

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a downvote; it's based on a misunderstanding, but isn't that the point of asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\exists y\exists z~(\varphi(y)\land\varphi(z)\leftrightarrow y=z)$ can be satisfied by the existence of two *distinct* entities where *at least* one does *not* satisfy the predicate $\varphi$.   If there is some $y,z$ where $y\neq z$ and at least $\lnot\varphi(y)$ or $\lnot\varphi(z)$, then these values do satisfy $\varphi(y)\land\varphi(z)\leftrightarrow y=z$.

In short, the fact that $(2\cdot 3=1\land 2\cdot 4=1)\leftrightarrow 3=4$ *is* valued as true does *not* suggest that either $3$ or $4$ are the multiplicative inverse of $2$.

---

You wish to state "For every (non-zero real) $x$, there is *some* $y$ that *is* its multiplicative inverse, *and* there is no other."

$$\forall x\in\Bbb R_{\neq 0}~\exists y\in\Bbb R_{\neq 0}~\forall z\in\Bbb R_{\neq 0}~\big(xy=1\land(xz=1\to z=y)\big)$$

Note: the parenthesis placement is important.

Comment: A nicety: $xy = 1$ doesn't have to be within the scope of the $z$ quantifier, and arguably the sentence is clearer if it isn't: 
$$\forall x\in\Bbb R_{\neq 0}~\exists y\in\Bbb R_{\neq 0}~\big(xy=1\land \forall z\in\Bbb R_{\neq 0}~(xz=1\to z=y)\big)$$

Comment: Indeed. @BrianO